# Calling function based on variable's value

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a very simple slideshow from scratch:

[image]

... which runs on 3 main variables:

```
var slideshowItem_place = 0;
var slideshowItem_position = 0;
var slideshowItem_limit = parseInt($('.slideshowImage_container').length) - 1;
```

The main function that makes the slideshow execute is this one:

```
function slideshow_animateSliding(){
  slideshowItem_position = 0 - (slideshowItem_place * 1280);
  $('#slideshowContent').stop().animate({'left':slideshowItem_position + 'px'}, 1000, 'swing');
  }
```

The thumbs, though...

[image]

... I don't know how to make them change automatically based on the visible slide when it's playing.

The thumbs code:

```
$('#slideshow_thumbsContainer').on('click', '> div:not(.slideshowThumbs_active)', function(){

  var $this_slideshowThumbs_notActive = $(this);
  var $this_slideshowThumbs_active = $('#slideshow_thumbsContainer > div.slideshowThumbs_active');

  function thumbsDeactivate(){
    // Deactivate currently slideshowThumbs_active animation...
  }

  function thumbsActivate(){
    thumbsDeactivate();
    // Activate clicked slideshowThumbs animation...
  }

  thumbsActivate();

});
```

My guess is that I should call the function **thumbsActivate()** in the one that runs the slideshow - **slideshow_animateSliding()** - just can't figure out the logic.

Here's some pseudo-code for what I need:

- if **slideshowItem_place = 0** then run **thumbsActivate(#slideshow_thumbOutline01)**
- if **slideshowItem_place = 1** then run **thumbsActivate(#slideshow_thumbOutline02)**
- etc...

Full [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RLWAp/).

Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: make use of a helper-class and everytime you loop in slideshowAutoplay() you check if the current-element has the helper class, get itś index and highlight the thumboutline with matching index, sth like that

Comment: Live example, please?

Comment: You need to optimize your code, you should use loops.I see alot alot of redundant code.

Comment: I'm a rookie on jQuery, therefore the non-optimized code...

Answer (score 0):

sth like

```
function slideshowAutoplay(){
    if (slideshowItem_place < slideshowItem_limit){
       slideshowItem_place ++;
       $('.slideshow_thumbInner').eq(slideshowItem_place).css('background-color','red');}
    else{
       slideshowItem_place = 0;   
       slideshow_animate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd need something more like: **$('.slideshow_thumbOutline').eq(slideshowItem_place).thumbsActivate();** called inside **slideshow_animateSliding()** instead of the autoplay function (it doesn't work, though)

Comment: then maybe you should write your function parametrized like : thumbsActivate(number); or write a separate one, and then call it with the active index like thumbsActivate(slideshowItem_place);

Comment: Can't seem to make it work... @john Smith, could you exemplify that on my fiddle, please?